# Limit the size of tmpdir

Tags: linux, mysql

I need to limit the disk usage of MySQL tmpdir so it does not "eat" all available disk space. There are around 30G available but i have seen mysqld using all of it to create a temp table.

My first approach was to implement disk quota but i ran into problems because I do not know how to set the quota on while the disk is in usage. It could be done probably on boot time in the init script but, I do not know if it is a good idea.

Any suggestions?
What would be best practices in this situation?

OS is RedHat

```
uname -a    
Linux www.myservername.com 2.6.18-194.17.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Sep 20 07:12:06 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.77, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: If MySQl runs under its own account, can't you put a [file system quota](http://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-disk-quotas.html) on it? Its probably not recommended in practice due to a potential for data loss, but it should accomplish you goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about it? AFAIK the temp tables are existing as long as they needed - for a query, but after they'll vanish. 
If you have as many active queries which needed 30GB temp tables that will cause you a lot more trouble than using all free space (I meant disk IO etc.)

You can still playng with ulimit, but that'll need service restart at least, so I am not sure if that is better than stting up quotas.

Answer (score 1):

If you have LVM, create a separate partition mount in required size. you can use the --tmpdir option to mysqld.

Check this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-files.html

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts in a virtual machine, I have decided that is too much of a risk for a production environment to force the quota on (-m). The issue only happened 1 time since I am taking care of this infrastructure and suspect it must be related to a dodgy query in the server creating a huge temp table.

Thanks all for the suggestions.